# jQuery Mobile execute a function after another is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to execute a function after my function "aggregateTimes" is complete.

This is the aggregateTime function that I want to finish before I run the function:

```
function aggregateTimes(date) {      
    $.ajax(
      {
        url: 'localhost/s',
        dataType : 'xml',
        success: function(data) { 
          $.each(data, function(index, calEvent){ 
          //do some work here            
        });              
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('error message');
      }
   });        
}
```

This is the way i call the functions right now:

```
$('#mainpage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {    
  aggregateTimes(new Date()); 
  $("#calendar").jqmCalendar(
    {
      events : eventsArray,
      months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
      startOfWeek : 0
    });
});
```

Is there a way to wait for the function "aggregateTimes" to finish, before the JQM?  Still a newbie, thanks!

Comment: Call that in the success handler of ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery ajax, use `complete` method to execute a function(s) after the ajax is complete.

```
function aggregateTimes(date){          

  $.ajax({
    url: 'localhost/s',
    dataType : 'xml',
    success: function(data){},
    error: function(){
      alert('error message');
    },
    complete: function(){
      myCustomFN();
      //do all your stuff here when the ajax is completed
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `aggregateTimes` function sends off an AJAX request, so it technically finishes before that request receives a response from the server. If you want code to run after the request receives the response, you can either move your code to the end of the `success` handler function you've already defined inside of `aggregateTimes`, or you can do the following:

```
function aggregateTimes(date){          
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/s',
        dataType : 'xml',
        success: function(data){ 
            $.each(data, function(index, calEvent){ 
                //do some work here            
            });              
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error message');
        }
    });
}

$('#mainpage').bind('pageinit', function (event) {
    var jqXhr = aggregateTimes(new Date());
    jqXhr.done(function () {
        $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
            events: eventsArray,
            months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            days: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
            startOfWeek: 0
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `ajax` function works as a [Promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/). So, if you return the 
jQuery ajax object, you can use the [`when...done`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) method to call another function.

That looks something like this:

```
$.when( functionThatReturnsPromise() ).done(function () }
  // do stuff when the promise is complete
});
```

If you return the ajax object in `aggregateTimes`, it will fill the role of "`functionThatReturnsPromise`" in the example above:

```
function aggregateTimes(date){          
    return $.ajax({
    ....
```

Returning the ajax object also makes it possible to simply treat the function call as a [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
aggregateTimes(new Date()).done(function () {
  // do stuff when aggregateTimes is done
});
```

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.promise` - https://api.jquery.com/promise/
- `jQuery.when` - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/
- `jQuery.ajax` - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- `deferred.done` - https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/
- jQuery Deferred Object - https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. One approach is to use callbacks. Add an additional parameter to `aggregateTimes()` that specifies the function to call on completion. It can be an anonymous function if that's your thing.

```
function aggregateTimes(date, callback){          

    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/s',
        dataType : 'xml',
        success: function(data){ 

             $.each(data, function(index, calEvent){ 
                 //do some work here            
             });
             callback();
         },
         error: function(){
             alert('error message');
         }
    });
}

// ...

aggregateTimes(new Date(), function() { 
    $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
        events : eventsArray,
        months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
        startOfWeek : 0
     });
});
```

An alternative, since you're using jQuery, is to use `$.Deferred`. Have `aggregateTimes()` return a Deferred object:

```
function aggregateTimes() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    //...

        success: function(data){ 

             $.each(data, function(index, calEvent){ 
                 //do some work here            
             });
             deferred.resolve();
         },

    //...

    return deferred;
}
```

Then call your second function when that `$.Deferred` completes.

```
var wait = aggregateTimes();

wait.done(function() {
    $("#calendar").jqmCalendar({
        events : eventsArray,
        months : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",             "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        days : ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
        startOfWeek : 0
     });
});
```